# creating a JSON object using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have hard time creating the following JSON format using PHP code below. Please suggest.

### PHP Code

```
$postArray = array(
    "MainPage" =>  array(
        "i_date"=> "10-10-2012",
        "i_location"=>$_POST["location-text"],
        "i_summary"=>$_POST["summary-text"],
    "SubPage" => "[" array(
        "first_name"=> $_POST["first-1"],
        "last_name"=>$_POST["last-1"]
         ),
         array(
            "first_name"=>$_POST["first-2"],
        "last_name"=>$_POST["last-2"]
         ) "]"
    )
);


array_push($postArray["MainPage"]["SubPage"], 
    array(
         "first_name"=>$_POST["first-3"],
         "last_name"=>$_POST["last-3"]
    )
);

$json = json_encode( $postArray );
```

Here is the final ouput I am trying to achieve.

```
{
  "MainPage":{
    "i_date":"2014-03-20",
    "i_location":"test",
    "i_summary":"test test",
    "SubPage":[
      {
        "first_name":"first name test1",
        "last_name":"last name test1"
      },
      {
        "first_name":"first name test2",
        "last_name":"last name test2"
      },
      {
        "first_name":"first name test3",
        "last_name":"last name test3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `"SubPage" => [ ... array(...) ... ]`, no quotes.

Comment: Get rid of the `"["` and `"]"`.

Comment: I tried removing the quotes but didn't work. I need the quotes for successful deserilisation.

Comment: Also I am not sure there is 0 between items. SubPage":{"first_name":"first name test1","last_name":"last name test1","0":{"first_name":"first name test2","last_name":"last name test2"}},"0":{"first_name":"test3","last_name":"test3"}}}". I need the "[" for deserilisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some changes to your original code which should give the results that you want.

```
$postArray = array(
    'MainPage' => array(
        'i_date' => '2014-03-20',
        'i_location' => $_POST["location-text"],
        'i_summary' => $_POST["summary-text"],
        'SubPage' => array(
            array(
                'first_name' => $_POST["first-1"],
                'last_name' => $_POST["last-1"]
            ),
            array(
                'first_name' => $_POST["first-2"],
                'last_name' => $_POST["last-2"]
            )                        
        )
    )
);

$postArray['MainPage']['SubPage'][] = array(
    'first_name' => $_POST["first-3"],
    'last_name' => $_POST["last-3"]
);

$json = json_encode($postArray);
```